# Configurable Switchs Selector Identification

Tags: switches, identification

Probably off topic.

I need help identifying a switch type.

[image]

The switch in the picture is embed in a camera to define configurations to the hardware.

I would like to use this kind of switch in a project, but i need a light.

Comment: what does this mean? ... `but i need a light` .... i think that something was lost in translation

Comment: A light would be a Brazilian expression for help. Like, when is dark, you need a light to find the exit. Kind of a guide or explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the DIP switch. Something like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]
Pretty easy to buy in almost every place with electronic stuff.

Comment: What about the rotary ones? What is the point? Can someone explain a little more? https://www.kenable.co.uk/images/SW03334_MAIN.jpg

Comment: @ahwelp Simple DIP switches are just... switches. They have 2,3,4,5 etc. on/off contacts. Rotary switches have one common and several 'code' pins, while turning they connects 'code' pins to common pin creating regular combinations like binary or Gray code.